# Why I am getting output as undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

Why I am getting { userName: undefined, password: undefined } as the final output when I pass userName and password parameters to setTimeout function ? I removed them from setTimeout and see then I got the expected outputs

```js
console.log("Starting");

displayUser = (userName, password, callback) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the displayUser function")
  setTimeout((userName, password) => {
    console.log("Iam inside the setTimeOut function");
    callback({
      userName: userName,
      password: password
    });
  }, 3000)
}

displayUser("Hasindu", "hasindu123", (user) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the call back function");
  console.log(user);
});

console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback function takes `username` and `password` parameters, but you never pass them as arguments.

You can give additional arguments to `setTimeout`, and they'll be passed as arguments to the callback.

```js
console.log("Starting");

displayUser = (userName, password, callback) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the displayUser function")
  setTimeout((userName, password) => {
    console.log("Iam inside the setTimeOut function");
    callback({
      userName: userName,
      password: password
    });
  }, 3000, userName, password)
}

displayUser("Hasindu", "hasindu123", (user) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the call back function");
  console.log(user);
});

console.log("end");
```

Or you could just leave out the parameters and the variables will be saved in the closure.

```js
console.log("Starting");

displayUser = (userName, password, callback) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the displayUser function")
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Iam inside the setTimeOut function");
    callback({
      userName: userName,
      password: password
    });
  }, 3000)
}

displayUser("Hasindu", "hasindu123", (user) => {
  console.log("Iam inside the call back function");
  console.log(user);
});

console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `setTimeout` callback is shadowing the `userName` and `password` variables. You either remove them from the parameters of the `setTimeout` callback or add them as arguments to the `setTimeout` call like so:

```
setTimeout((userName, password) => {
    console.log("Iam inside the setTimeOut function");
    callback({
      userName: userName,
      password: password
    });
  }, 3000, userName, password)
```

Comment: Thank you  for answering I didn't see it